# mozRequestFullScreen(); not working. Why?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
function doit()
{
    document.getElementById('id1').mozRequestFullScreen();
}
```

But it doesn't work. Though it does for [this site](http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/26517/using-the-browsers-new-html5-fullscreen-capabilities/):

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ispiro/LXtPA/).

Why? (I'm using FireFox.)

Comment: what is the result of the call?  try `var result = document.getElementById('id1').mozRequestFullScreen();` and setting a breakpoint to inspect the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSFiddle results are displayed within an iframe. Unless this frame explicitly allows fullscreen by adding the mozallowfullscreen attribute it will silently fail:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-mozallowfullscreen

Comment: I tried this in a web project (ASP.Net) as well and it doesn't work either. With no iframe there.

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it certainly has nothing to do with ASP, as that is the server side language.

Comment: The problem was lack of user-interaction. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14244427/939213 .