# FullScreen works onclick but not onload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying the code from [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/javascript-full-screen-api) to start fullscreen mode. It works if executed `onclick` , but not `onload`. (I've also discovered that setting an `alert` before it will disable it unless the `alert` is clicked immediately.) So perhaps the problem is that sometimes the browser isn’t 'ready' for fullscreen.

So what is the last event fired when a page is completely ready? Or is the solution different?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fullscreen requires user interaction to initiate. It's a security feature.

Imagine if some pop-up could force you into fullscreen mode, lock your mouse pointer, and start playing an advertisement without your permission.

Having a 'enable full screen' link or button who's visibility is toggled in the document 'fullscreenchange' event handler seems like a practical approach.

Answer (score 0):

well this might help [Fullscreen script](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7645-script-to-automatically-display-webpage-in-fullscreen)

But I agree with [LastCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884862/lastcoder)

> Fullscreen requires user interaction to initiate. It's a security feature.
>
> Imagine if some pop-up could force you into fullscreen mode, lock your mouse pointer, and start playing an advertisement without your permission.

Comment: museum alert. the script isn't working in newer browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to do this myself then I came to this site [Fullscreen API Phishing Attacks](http://feross.org/html5-fullscreen-api-attack/)

Basically, if fullscreen mode was allowed onload, we don't know if site is actual website...fake site can have the lock logo saying it's safe, etc.