# Is their anyway to dispaly a website in fullscreen without user interaction?

Tags: jquery, apache

here in my script,i'l make it to exist in fullscreen on button click,but i need to display the page in fullscreen initially without any user interaction.

```js
function requestFullScreen(element) {
    // Supports most browsers and their versions.
    var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullscreen;

    if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
        requestMethod.call(element);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        if (wscript !== null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }
}
var element = document.body; // Make the body go full screen.
requestFullScreen(element);
```

```html
    <body>
<input type="button" value="click to toggle fullscreen" onclick="requestFullScreen(element)">
```

Comment: are you tried with on ready function

Comment: ya..but it shows error as given below

Comment: "Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture."

Comment: this link may be helps you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244397/fullscreen-works-onclick-but-not-onload/14244427#14244427)

Comment: thanks KVK..it helps me a lot

Answer (score -1):

you just use your full screen code in the bellow block.it will execute your code when the page is loaded.

$(document).ready(function() {

});